# Why does dplyr put quotes around my variables

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I'm using "pivot_wider" (also tried "spread") function in dplyr to rearrange some data. But when I use the function, the output variables get weird `` ` ` `` around them (shown below). I don't see any mention of this [in the documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) and I haven't found anything on it on StackExchange. I've tried changing the variables into num and int before running the function, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the quotes.

The problem is that if I want to do any operations on the new variables, I now need to write it as `` `2014` ``, which gets old fast. Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I need to do to my data before/after I run this?

```
Original data
       ID       group   var
       <dbl>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1     4548     2014    18 
 2     4549     2014    19 
 3     4550     2015    20 


pivot_wider(names_from=group, values_from=var)
Original data
       ID       `2014`  `2015`
       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     4548     18      NA 
 2     4549     19      NA 
 3     4550     NA      20
```

Comment: 2014 isn't a valid variable name on its own.  You need the backticks to allow using nonstandard variable names.  Unless you add something to make it valid - maybe rename 2014 to X2014 or something like that you'll just have to deal with the backticks.

Comment: From the `make.names()` help: "A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words."

Comment: For more background on R's strict rules on valid names you might be interested in this [brief overview of on non-syntactic names in R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic) from the Advanced R book.

Comment: Thanks both Dason and Dave2e, that's helpful for understanding the logic. I've been using R for three years but I'm obviously still behind in some areas. To Dave2e's point, I've tired adding suffixes (e.g. 2014x) but predictably get the same problem. So it looks like the only way to get around this is with a prefix like with `pivot_wider(names_from=group, values_from=var, names_prefix="x")`   Also thanks to aosmith for the good reference. I'll have a read of it.